Reference book for Binomial Theorem with Negative Exponents
I understand the Binomial Theorem, and have practiced it to a reasonable extent.
Is there a book which has examples and practice questions on Binomial Theorem with negative exponents.
(Note: I don't need proofs and properties, or abstract math. My primary interest is to practice enough numerical examples to be comfortable in applications. As an example, I would like to prove the mean and variance of the negative binomial distribution using the negative binomial series).

Why not give an example of a problem you want to solve, to start the process off? You cannot always rely on a text book being available that exactly meets your needs, the pure maths universe is way too large for that.

Added an example. Negative binomial distribution

The Abramowitz-Stegun book in https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf
has examples for negative exponents in equations 3.6.10 to 3.6.12 and 3.6.14.
